I get error 0xc000007b when launching Unity Editor
Every single time I attempt to launch Unity the message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application." without even creating any Unity logs. Any help is appreciated. Also, my OS is Windows 11.
I don't know what to do, I've tried most solutions on the internet, uninstalled and reinstalled unity, tried different versions, though nothing changed.
I have used Dependencies to check the dlls and it looks like some don't pass the checksum (optix.6.0.0.dll, OpenImageDenoise.dll, etc), but I can't figure out any place to download them. Is this a red herring or am I missing something?


Did you have a read at this https://discussions.unity.com/t/finally-found-solution-to-the-0xc000007b-error-at-startup/785751 ? It's probably related .. there is a couple of things you could try including defender settings etc
